# Jplayer playlist div id not showing - playlist not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jplayer

I have jplayer working perfectly with PHP MYSQLi with audio tracks displaying, but challenge comes when I want to display the current playing file on top of the player with `<div id="playlist"></div>` but when applied using javascript,  the whole playlist disappears, but when i remove the triggering code from the javascript, the playlist appears. Here is my code

Before current item playing - code (playlist shows, player working fine)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var cssSelector = { jPlayer: "#playlist_1", cssSelectorAncestor: "#playlist_container" };
        var playlist = <?php echo $playlist;?>;
        var options = { swfPath: "assets/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.swf", supplied: "<?php echo $supplied;?>", smoothPlayBar: true, autoPlay: true, keyEnabled: true, shuffleOnLoop: true, wmode: "window", free: Boolean, };
        var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);
    });
</script>
```

[Playlist shows - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBrav.gif)

With current item playing - code(playlist disappears)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var cssSelector = { jPlayer: "#playlist_1", cssSelectorAncestor: "#playlist_container" };
        var playlist = <?php echo $playlist;?>;
        var options = { swfPath: "assets/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.swf", supplied: "<?php echo $supplied;?>", smoothPlayBar: true, autoPlay: true, keyEnabled: true, shuffleOnLoop: true, wmode: "window", free: Boolean, };
        var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);
    });

    $("#playlist_1").on($.jPlayer.event.ready, function (event) {
        var current = myPlaylist.current;
        var playlist = myPlaylist.playlist;
        $.each(playlist, function (index, obj) {
            if (index == current) {
                $("#playing").html("<span class='artist-name'>" + obj.artist + "</span>" + "<br>" + "<span class='track-name'>" + obj.title + "</span>");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Playlist disappears - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdk8m.gif)

Output html

```
<div id="playlist_container" class="jp-audio">
    <div id="jplayer"></div>
    <div class="jp-content jp-type-playlist">
        <div id="playlist_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
        <div id="playing"></div>
        <ul class="jp-controls">
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/player/3.png" alt="Image"></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/player/5.png" alt="Image"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jp-interface">
            <div class="jp-progress">
                <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                    <div class="jp-play-bar">
                        <b></b>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jp-playlist">
        <ul>
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="jp-no-solution">
        <span>Update Required</span>
        To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
    </div>
</div>
```

Anything am not doing